# ImportError: cannot import name 'make_meta' from 'dask.dataframe.core'

Tags: dask

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask_geopandas as dg
```

When importing above, I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import dask_geopandas as dg
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\dask_geopandas\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import backends
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\dask_geopandas\backends.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dask.dataframe.core import get_parallel_type, make_meta
ImportError: cannot import name 'make_meta' from 'dask.dataframe.core' (C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py)
```

Have someone encountered to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fabel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67794863/1785661) explains why this error happens, here's what can be done about it now.

This issue fixed in [dask_geopandas pull request #47](https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas/pull/47), but not yet released (as of 2021-06-01).

The solution thus is to either

- downgrade dask to an older version (e.g. `2014.4.1`)
- install dask-geopandas from the latest `master`
- wait for the next dask-geopandas release, which is [probably coming soon](https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas/issues/49)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the `dask_geopandas` module refers to `dask.dataframe.core` from which it tries to import **make_meta**, but **make_meta** is not in the latest version of `dask` https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/_modules/dask/dataframe/core.html
**make_meta** moved to `dask.dataframe.utils.make_meta` I suppose.

Solution, you need to coordinate the versions of the libraries with each other.

Try to use `geopandas` insted of `dask_geopandas`